# How to check if Cipher's encryption was okey?

Tags: windows, encryption

In windows7 I use the command below, but somhow it seems to not work.

Maybe something must be added ?

> cipher /K /ECC:521 /R:winEnc /Y /A  /E / S:C:/test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do a lot of things at once. You can do plenty of different things with the `cipher` utility, but only one set of parameters can work in one command. To see the parameter sets it accepts, type `cipher /?`. The help printed specifically notes that if `/K` is supplied, other options will be ignored.

To create a new EFS certificate with a key size of 521 and add it to the user's certificate store:

```
cipher /K /ECC:521
```

To create a recovery key file pair called titled `winEnc` with a size of 521:

```
cipher /R:winEnc /ECC:521
```

To show the thumbprint of the user's newest certificate:

```
cipher /Y
```

There does not appear to be an option `/A`.

To mark the directory `C:\test` as encrypting new files in it:

```
cipher /E /S:C:\test
```

Any one of those four commands will work, but not all of them at once.

Comment: Yes, I messed up something. Is the switch /K creating a certificate for the folder encrypted with /E ? And what is the standard algorithm with the /K switch ?  Thank you very much

Comment: @GiaRui If you don't already have an EFS certificate in your certificate store, one is automatically created when you use `/E`, but you can't specify `/ECC` then. Otherwise, `/E` uses the newest certificate in the user's certificate store. If you create a certificate that way or use `/K` without `/ECC`, you get a 2048-bit RSA key pair (as opposed to an ECDSA one).

Comment: That's good. Is e.g. /ECC:521 is a weaker or stronger algorithm ? May I use also the /H switch along with /E ? May I use the encrypte folder with the /K certificate also in another system ? Thanks

Comment: @GiaRui [This paper](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8951-CryptoAuth-RSA-ECC-Comparison-Embedded-Systems-WhitePaper.pdf) says a 2048-bit RSA key is roughly equivalent to a 224-bit ECC key. You can use `/H` with `/E`, as shown in `cipher /?`. You will only be able to decrypt EFS files on another system if you [migrate the EFS key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722147) used to encrypt them.

Comment: Thank you, Just the foldername changed it's color late to green. I will post an answer on how I tried to use Cipher with a batch-file. Hope it is okey.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the answer above I try to use a .bat file to execute multiple commands.

/H is to include hidden files/folders

/W to delete securely deallocated data (the file/folder that were created in plain before)

> cipher /K /ECC:521

pause

cipher /R:winEnc

pause

cipher /Y

pause

cipher /E /S:C:/Users/A/Documents/test /H

pause

cipher /W:C:/Users/A/Documents/test